# Javascript - smartest solution for many conditions

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

In javascript I have a function, where I have too many conditions. I wonder what will be the smartest solution to rework this function.

Currently I have it like this. Of course there are more than 20 conditions, just for example I have 3 here:

```
function checkURL(pageName) (
let urlPart = '';
if (pageName == 'something') { urlPart = "main/contact";}
if (pageName == 'anythingelse') { urlPart = "administration/user";}
if (pageName == 'another page') { urlPart = "administration/country";}

return urlPart;
)
```

I was thinking to rework it with `switch/case` or put the `pageName` variable into array and `urlPart` as well, and then just find the `pageName` position in array and compare with `urlPart` position, e.g.:

```
    function checkURL(pageName) (
const pg = ["something", "anythingelse", "another page"];
const url = ["main/contact", "administration/user", "administration/country"];

let index1 = pg.indexOf(pageName);
if (index1>=0) {return url[index1];} else {return ''; }
)
```

The problem might be with matching the same position of both elements in array, as people will add more and more items to the array and they can do a mistake where the position in first array will not match the correct position in second array when we will have 50 items maybe.

Comment: Create an object keyed with `pageName`s, and valued with `urlPart`s. That way the there's necessarily no need for cheks at all, just return `pageUrls[pageName]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use checks at all for this.

Simply create an object that is used as a kind of lookup table. So in the case of your code, something like this:

```
const urls = {
  "something": "main/contact",
  "anythingelse": "administration/user",
  "another page": "administration/country"
}
```

Now you don't need to run a bunch of checks, but a single check (that the urls object has a key that matches `pageName`). If that check succeeds, return the result. Otherwise, return a default / error page.

```
function checkURL(pageName) (
  return urls[pageName] || "main/pageNotFound";
)
```

Comment: Wow, I was trying with for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object1)) but your solution is absolutely the best! I am really surprised. Thank you!

Comment: shoudn't it be rather `urls[pageName] ?? "main/pageNotFound"`

Comment: @serge For most cases they do the same. However, if one of the potential urls is an empty string `""` then your solution is better, because the `||` operator would consider an empty string falsy, whereas the `??` operator wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

load the settings from a json file, like this:

```js
const jsonText = `{
  "pages": {
    "something": "main/contact",
    "anythingelse": "administration/user"
  }
}`;
let pages = JSON.parse(jsonText).pages;

console.log('pages["something"]:', pages['something']);
console.log('pages["anythingelse"]:', pages['anythingelse']);
console.log('pages["not_found"]:', pages['not_found']);
```